# Why is the relative pronoun put in the dative case? why feminine? (Greek)

Tags: greek, grammar-identification, greek-translation, plato, relative-pronouns

I was a little stumped, here, when I came across the feminine relative pronoun ᾗ.

> ἴσως δή, εἶπον, παρὰ τὸ ἔθος γελοῖα ἂν φαίνοιτο πολλὰ περὶ τὰ νῦν
> λεγόμενα, εἰ πράξεται ᾗ λέγεται.
>
> καὶ μάλα, ἔφη.
>
> [Plato's Republic, Book 5, section 452a](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.01.0167%3Abook%3D5%3Asection%3D452a)

Here's how I translated the passage:

> "Perhaps then," I said, "being contrary to custom, many things related to what we're saying should seem ridiculous, if they will be done according to what is said."
>
> "Yes," he said.

First, I'm unsure as to why ᾗ is in the feminine singular. Is this an arbitrary choice? Or is there a logic to it? For several reasons, I would expect the neuter instead of the feminine.

Second, why the dative case? Nominative makes more sense to me. Is there a better way to translate the dative than the one I gave?

I think the best translation would be, "if what is said will be done", but this would be more liberal, and I wanted to understand how the nuts and bolts worked first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an adverbial use of the relative and has its own entry in LSJ. It's used in comparative clauses, for example.

LSJ:

> **ᾗ**, dat. sg. fem. of relat. Pron. ὅς, ἥ, ὅ, in adverb. sense ... II. of Manner, *how*, *as*.

Smyth (§2463):

> Comparative clauses of quality or manner are introduced by ὡς *as*, ὥσπερ, καθάπερ *just as*, ὅπως, ᾗ, ὅπῃ, ᾗπερ *as*

Comment: Great find. So should you translate it, then, "if they will be done as they are said"? I assume that πολλὰ carries over as the subject (for both verbs).

Comment: This sounds analogous to the Latin feminine ablative *qua*.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta You're right! The LSJ entry gives the following quote from Aristotle:  "ᾗ ἄνθρωπος" =  "*qua* man" (Arist. *EN* 1096b2)